# Android deeplinking: match url only when no path

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking

Given the following URLS:

```
1. www.example.com

2. www.example.com/a
```

Via [deeplinking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html), I want my app to only react on `1` and **not** `2`.

```
            <data
                android:host="*.example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/"
                android:scheme="http"/>
```

This will, of course, catch all `www.example.com/...` urls, how can I match only `www.example.com` without any path and not match `www.example.com/a`?

Comment: Did you try `<data android:host="example.com" android:path="" android:scheme="http"/>` ?

Comment: That didnt work, but <data android:host="example.com" android:path="/" android:scheme="http"/> did, so the trick was to use path instead of pathPrefix od pathPattern. 
If you post this as an answer, i'll accept it ;) Thanks!

Comment: You did find the correct answer. You can write it and also accept it ;)

Answer (score 6):

Here's what worked for me, set path empty and include a tools:ignore to avoid lint errors.

```
<data
     android:host="*.example.com"
     android:path=""
     android:scheme="http"
     tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError"
            />
```

Answer (score 2):

Using 'path' instead of 'pathPrefix' or 'pathPattern' worked, so:

```
        <data
            android:host="*.example.com"
            android:path="/"
            android:scheme="http"/>
```

matches `www.example.com` as well as `www.example.com/`, but not `www.example.com/a`, so exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Does this still work? For me it only works for `http://example.com/`, not `http://www.example.com` unfortunately

Comment: Nope. Only www.example.com/ works

Answer (score 1):

Old question but what worked for me was adding two data inputs

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="*.example.com"
                    android:path=""
                    tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError"
                    android:scheme="https" />

                <data
                    android:host="*.example.com"
                    android:path="/"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Adding just one of them would handle either `www.example.com` or `www.example.com/`.
You can also put them in different intent filters.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and find a solution for matching nude domain like `www.example.com`

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com"/>
</intent-filter>
```

The key is to add a `intent-filter` without any `path`-like attribute.

Comment: wouldn't that also react to www.example.com/a?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to match both `http://example.com/` and `http://example.com`, I can confirm @Anigif comment: using a single `data` element containing `path="/"` doesn't work anymore, as it only matches `http://example.com/`, but does not match `http://example.com`.

However, adding two data elements to the same intent works:

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="*.example.com" android:path="/"/>
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="*.example.com" android:path=""/>
```

This matches `http://example.com/` and `http://example.com` but does not match `http://example.com/a`.